# ¿Por qué un script de Bash se ejecuta correctamente pero no si lo hago a través de crontab?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos, crontab

En primera instancia tengo un archivo bash el cual ejecuta una pagina web en php. Ya he verificado el archivo bash y esta funciona.

Ejecuto.

```
sh /var/www/html/app/cron/prueba.bash
```

Tanto con usuario común como con root y funciona.

El bash ejecuta algo como esto:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -s "http://xxxxxx/app/pruebas.php"
```

Ahora el problema está en el crontab.

Ya he visto el log de cron y el cron sí está corriendo; por ejemplo creando un archivo .txt lo hace;  pero la tarea del bash no la está ejecutando.

Entonces, lo que hice fue capturar el mensaje que devuelve la ejecución del crontab.

```
00 10 * * * root /var/www/html/app/cron/prueba.bash >/dev/null 2> /var/www/html/app/cron/prueba.log
```

Al entrar al archivo prueba.log encuentro que quedá registrado lo siguiente:

```
/bin/sh: root: no se encontró la orden
```

Agradezco alguna ayuda o sugerencia que se pueda brindar.

Answer (score 5):

El problema está en que, tal cuál como te lo muestra el error, el comando `root` no está disponible.

El formato un archivo crontab se establece en `man 5 crontab`, y establece seis campos: cinco de tiempo y lo restante de la línea es el comando a correr.

Los valores aceptados por campo son:

```
field          allowed values
-----          --------------
minute         0-59
hour           0-23
day of month   1-31
month          1-12 (or names, see below)
day of week    0-7 (0 or 7 is Sun, or use names)
```

El sexto campo es el comando a correr. Por ejemplo.

```
* * * * * /ruta/a/programa
* * * * * bash /ruta/a/programa
* * * * * comando
```

En tu caso, el programa que pusiste es el inexistente `root`, y la `shell` que trató de correr ese comando te lo mostró al decirte.

> /bin/sh: root: no se encontró la orden

Si quieres correr ese script, usa el programa adecuado o agrégale permisos de ejecución y pon la ruta completa.

Por ejemplo

```
chmod +x /var/www/html/app/cron/prueba.bash
```

Y en tu crontab pones

```
00 10 * * * /var/www/html/app/cron/prueba.bash
```

O en su defecto, en lugar de cambiar los permisos, sólo pones.

```
00 10 * * * bash /var/www/html/app/cron/prueba.bash
```

Si quieres editar sólo el archivo crontab de tu usuario, simplemente con `crontab -e`, en cambio, si quieres editar el del superusuario, te puedes *loggear* como superusuario y correr el mismo comando o con `sudo crontab -e`

Answer (score 0):

Creo que en vez de **root**, el comando que buscas para ejecutar la orden como superusuario es **sudo**, si no buscas ejecutarlo como superusuario, tal vez tambien lo estes confundiendo con el comando **sh**.

Un saludo