# Linux crontab, creando rutinas

Tags: linux, servidor, cron, crontab, task

queria hacer una prueba en mi servidor linux, queria que **cada minuto** mostrara por consola `hola mundo`, para ello hice los siguiente:

```
user@server: crontab -e
```

Y luego de abrirlo con **nano** añado al final del fichero :

```
#prueba task para que haga 'hola mundo' cada minuto
* * * * * echo "hola mundo"
```

Se supone que con eso, mientras este haciendo cosas en el bash de linux me debe aparecer un `hola mundo` cada minuto, pero me quedo ahi esperando mas de un minuto a que salga el mensaje pero **no sale nada**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El funcionamiento del crontab es diferente al que esperas.

Lo que tú quieres es que imprima un mensaje en TU terminal, pero el cron tab corre en otro lado que NO es tu terminal.

Hasta donde sé, es posible hacerlo al menos de dos maneras. La primera es imprimiendo en la interfaz a la que está asociada tu terminal. La segunda es jugar prudentemente con los descriptores de archivo asociados al proceso que corre en tu terminal. Eso lo abordaré al final de mi respuesta.

Primero que nada, fuera del comando a ejecutar, tu crontab está perfecto. Tal vez te sirva darle un vistaso a una [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/254346/por-qu%C3%A9-un-script-de-bash-se-ejecuta-correctamente-pero-no-si-lo-hago-a-trav%C3%A9s/254403#254403) que dí hace tiempo y tratar de programar otra tarea como crear un archivo en una dirección específica, etc.

Para el caso específico de tu pregunta, puedes usar el comando `tty` para ver a qué terminal o pseudo-terminal está conectada tu standard input. También puedes con `who`

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/0
$ who
tu usuario      pts/0        2019-08-11 02:15 (tu ip)
```

Entonces puedes jugar haciendo algo como

```
$ echo hola: $(date) > /dev/pts/0
hola: Sun Aug 11 02:23:48 CDT 2019
```

Y entonces eso lo puedes poner en tu archivo crontab. Es decir, primero obtienes la interfaz asociada (el /dev/{pts|tty}/{numero}) y a lo obtenido le envías el mensaje, quedándote tu archivo crontab de la siguiente manera.

```
* * * * * echo hola: $(date) > <el resultado de tty>
```

En mi caso sería algo así:

```
* * * * * echo hola: $(date) > /dev/pts/0
```

Y cada minuto te joderá con ese mensajito en tu terminal.

Como aclara @Trauma en un comentario de esta publicación, no siempre tienes la misma interfaz asociada a tu terminal, por lo tanto tendrás que valerte de otros métodos si lo que quieres es escribir eso (espero que no). Osea, sería divertido pero hay mejores cosas en qué divertirse.

El comando `write` hace eso por ti, escribe un mensaje a un usuario. Entonces, el crontab podría quedar de la siguiente manera.

```
* * * * * echo hola: $(date) | write tu_usuario
```

La segunda forma que se me ocurre para escribir, y ejecutar comandos, en tu terminal, o en la de quien sea, es jugando con los descriptores de archivo. Puedes usar varios programas o estrategias, desde el *debugger*, cosas raras (que siempre me fallan) con pipes, o hacer un script de python como este.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import os
import fcntl
import termios

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    sys.stderr.write("uso ttyecho.py pts/n command\n")
    sys.exit(1)

fd = os.open("/dev/" + sys.argv[1], os.O_RDWR)
cmd=sys.argv[2]

for i in range(len(cmd)):
    fcntl.ioctl(fd, termios.TIOCSTI, cmd[i])

fcntl.ioctl(fd, termios.TIOCSTI, '\n')
os.close(fd)
```

Que cuando lo ejecutas de la siguiente manera `python ttyecho.py pts/0 "touch uno1"` ejecuta en la terminal referida el comando `touch uno1`.

Sólo que para que se ejecute en a través de una tarea programada, tendrías que editar el archivo crontab de root.

```
$ sudo crontab -e -u root 
# O simplemente 
$ sudo crontab -e
```

Y añadir.

```
* * * * * python /ruta/completa/a/ttyecho.py pts/0 "echo hola, estas siendo invadido"
```

Donde te recuerdo que pts/0 varía en cada usuario o cada ingreso. Podrías obtenerla con un sencillo *command substitution*, pero eso es tema de otra pregunta.

Y eso ejecutaría cada minuto un molesto comando en esa terminal, no sólo lo imprime, como en el ejemplo anterior, sino que fuerza a que la terminal lo escriba y ejecute.

Comment: Buena respuesta, pero para mi gusto te has quedado a medias. Deberías indicar que tendrá que hacer eso cada vez que quiera hacer la prueba, porque el *handle* de su terminal puede variar en cada `login` o con cada ventana de terminal que abra. Y de paso, recomendarle que haga `man write`.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, @Trauma,  lo pensé pero como no especificaba que estaba compartiendo su servidor, aproveche ese pretexto para que por flojera no abordara ese punto.